# Como soluciono error "Console is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy empezando con NodeJS y cuando intento ejecutar un archivo llamado "index.js" me salta este error:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\ArchivosNodeJS>node index.js
C:\Users\Usuario\ArchivosNodeJS\index.js:19
Console.log(add(1,2));


ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\flaza\ArchivosNodeJS\index.js:19:1)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

A continuación pongo el código:

```
function add(x1, x2){
    return x1+x2;
}

function substract(x1, x2){
    return x1 - x2;
}
function multiply(x1, x2){
    return x1*x2;
}
function divide(x1, x2){
    if(x2==0){
        Console.log('No se puede dividir por 0');
    }else{
        return x1/x2;
    }
}

Console.log(add(1,2));
```

No se si es cosa de que tengo mal instalado el NodeJS o si tengo que instalar algo adicional...

Comment: `Console.log` -> `console.log`

Comment: Gracias! No esperaba que fuese tan estricto el lenguaje

Comment: No hay problema. Agregare una respuesta para personas que tenga el mismo problema en el futuro =)

Answer (score 1):

El objeto `Console` (C en mayuscula) no es reconocido por Javascript, por eso te indica que no esta definido.

Debes usar `console.log(...)` en minusculas.